# How to draw this in Wxwidget C++

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am using Wxwidget with C++ and IDE Code::Block. Now, I want to draw a tree like image below, please help me:

[image: image here]

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no such capability in wxWidgets readily, however there is a library you should look at [wxShapeFramework](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxsf/).

Answer (score 0):

**This is what I need:**

How can I create diagrams with connected nodes?

A not very good idea is to create a wxPanel for each node and then move the panels around with drag and drop (wxWidgets does not support overlapping components, and besides this will get very slow when you have a lot of nodes)

One way is to manually draw them on a panel

> (http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Drawing_on_a_panel_with_a_DC)

However, several people already went through that and provided various add-ons you can try :

> wxArt2D
>
> wxShapeFramework
>
> wxWorkspaceView